# Cisco, Router can communicate; hosts cannot

Tags: cisco, router, nat, ping, snat

I am learning CCNA related tasks, I have picked up a Cisco 1900 Series router. I am attempting to set it up behind my existing router (Comcast standard router).

My "Real" network is 10.0.0.0/24
My goal is to create a 192.168.1.0 network using this router.

I have manually assigned gigabitEthernet0/0 10.0.0.111 as the "WAN" side of the router.

Below is my startup configuration, the router can communicate with the 10.0.0.0/24 network and ping google or 8.8.8.8 just fine. However, a host connected to the LAN side of the router will pull a DHCP address but cannot ping outside the router.

```
!
! Last configuration change at 06:00:44 UTC Wed Jan 6 2021
!
version 15.8
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname archnet
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
! card type command needed for slot/vwic-slot 0/0
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!


!
!
ip dhcp pool LAN1
 network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.1.1
 dns-server 8.8.8.8
 lease 7
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1921/K9 sn FTX170683J5
license boot module c1900 technology-package securityk9
license boot module c1900 technology-package datak9
!
!
!
redundancy
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Embedded-Service-Engine0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.0.111 255.255.255.0
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip nat inside source list 1 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/0
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.1
!
ip access-list extended NAT
 permit ip any 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.255
!
ipv6 ioam timestamp
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
line aux 0
line 2
 no activation-character
 no exec
 transport preferred none
 transport output lat pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login
 transport input none
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
!
end
```

From my basic and beginner understanding of Networks, this appears to be a NAT issue. But that is why I am here, I have attempted as you can see to setup NAT and it doesn't work.

I am clearly doing something incorrectly, please steer me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For NAT to work, you must specify a [standard access list](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/ios-firewall/23602-confaccesslists.html#standacl) to identify the traffic that should be NATted. You reference the access list (`source list 1`) correctly, but you have not created the access list.

Correct NAT config would be:

```
ip nat inside source list 1 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload
access-list 1 permit 192.168.1.0 0.255.255.255
```

Your extended access list `NAT` cannot be used for this, since the `ip nat inside` command accepts a standard access list only.

Comment: Also, remove the unnecessary (and incorrect) `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/0` (that's proxy-arp)